# YTD starts from April instead of January

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, slicers

How can I create a chart that shows a 'YTD' data that starts from April and ends in March next year?

Answer (score 2):

Answer lies in the the last parameter `year_end_date`. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/totalytd-function-dax). There's an example in there too.

I suggest that you can use a more effective Google search keyword to find this next time. You can search for something like `power bi dax totalytd different year start`.